# Correct php header or encoding for json files with file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I have a file for a JSON file like this (with latin characters):

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($content);
?>
```

And i have another file that uses file_get_contents but the json_decode fails.

The only way that work to parse the json file is if I do a preg_replace of some characters...

```
<?php
$doc = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = json_decode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $doc));
$doc = reset($doc);
?>
```

Not a very clean way so i think that my header or encoding has a problem... Any ideas?
Thanks
EDITED:
Here is the file:
https://data.hexis-graphics.com/public/json/documents/cats/catalogue/langs/fr,es,it,sv,dk,de,us,xfr,xen/
And on this validator https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ I get :

```
Error:Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.[Code 29, Structure 0]
Error:Expecting object or array, not string.[Code 1, Structure 1]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 1]
```

Comment: Add your json so we can check it please.

Comment: `json_decode()` does not need any manual manipulation to work properly with properly formatted json. Please use `json_last_error();` and `json_last_error_msg();` to get a clue what really is going wrong.

Comment: I added on the description the url to the file... and json_last_error and message only sais that the json is not valid

Comment: I see it is the UTF8-bom, and i don't think there is another solution for it sadly

Comment: Do you think that i can send the response without the BOM?